# "if else" in php when both "if" and "else" have same actions

Tags: php, if-statement

I know this is basic, but I can't find an answer. I would like to do the following using PHP:

```
If A is true
    do X 
    do Y [X has to be executed before Y can be executed]
Else
    do just Y [executing X is not required]
```

Do I need to put Y in twice, as above (i.e., in both the If and the Else statements), or is there a way to write this so that I only have to write Y once?

Comment: Is this something for you: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.goto.php

Comment: To execute something conditionally, you put it in an `if` or `else` block. To execute something regardless, you don't. so `if A { x() } Y()` seems to fit that description, no?

Comment: @SuperDJ: Why would you even suggest something as hideous as a `goto`? They should've never added that to PHP, especially not as late as 5.3. It's ridiculous... in spite of all its faults, I like PHP, but this one still makes my blood boil

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if ($a == true) {
    doX();
}

doY();
```

Answer (score 1):

just put something like

```
if a is true 
    do x
end if

do y
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are confident that running Y is OK regardless of wherever or not X is executed, then I would bin the else part of the if block and simply do the following

```
<?php
$DEBUG = true;

if ($DEBUG) {
    // Do X
}

// Do Y

?>
```